# Compiling Issue with SFBAudioEngine

Tags: iphone, ios5, flac

I want to play Flac files in ios and downloaded code from: [SFBAudioEngine](https://github.com/sbooth/SFBAudioEngine/downloads)

I added frameworks for mac os and it build successfully but when I run app it crashes and gives

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/dumb.framework/Versions/A/dumb
Referenced from: /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFBAudioEngine-frrtbwxsqekjtmekpdfikqaqcsso/Build/Products/Debug/SimplePlayer.app/Contents/MacOS/SimplePlayer
Reason: image not found
```

And When I am trying to make build for ios app It is giving error

```
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1
```

Please help me to run this app .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the dumb framework is not being loaded. You need to make sure it's located at this path on your computer:

```
@rpath/dumb.framework
```

And make sure this file exists before running your app:

```
@rpath/dumb.framework/Versions/A/dumb
```

Comment: I have added dumb.framework in my project. Can you tell me where can I check this path ?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the Frameworks folder inside the `SFBAudioEngine` folder. [check](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html) for @rpath details